# Constructing proper regex redirect for multiple pages with variable directories

Tags: redirect

Something happened to our WordPress site and we ended up with thousands of 404s to basically the same page (probably a plugin conflict or deactivation).

The actual page is at `example.com/c/circlek.htm`.

The 404 errors follow this pattern:

```
example.com/movie-review/page/18/c/circlek.htm
example.com/movie-review/page/17/c/circlek.htm
example.com/movie-review/page/155/c/circlek.htm
example.com/movie-review/page/188/c/circlek.htm
example.com/movie-review/page/191/c/circlek.htm
```

and so on and on and on...

The only variation is the numerical folders that do not exist. I could create 2,000 redirects for each one but I'm sure there's a way to create a regex redirect to address all possible variations. I think I know that the expression (.*) should match the numerical folder, regardless of number of digits but I'm stuck otherwise.

So, anything like https://example.com/movie-review/page/18/c/circlek.htm or https://example.com/movie-review/page/191/c/circlek.htm, etc. should redirect to https://example.com/c/circlek.htm

This is what I'm coming up with and I know it must be incomplete:

```
RewriteRule ^movie-review/page/(.*)/ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Thank you marc_s for the excellent edits. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: How about:
RewriteRule ^movie-review/page/(.*)/c/circlek.htm /c/circlek.htm [R=301,NC,L]